# ASP.NET Core pass Null parameters to controller endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-binding

Using a model binder it is possible to pass a NULL complex type to a controller endpoint.

This solution does not work for all controller endpoints, rebuilding the model is also not straight forward.

Is there a better solution to pass a NULL complex type parameter in ASP.NET Core?

This functionality works as expected (allows NULLs) using .NET Standard without any modifications.

Using the following `IModelBinder` and `IModelBinderProvider`:

```
public class NullModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(BreakSize))
            {
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(NullModelBinder));
            }

            return null;
        }
}

public class NullModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
            // If null than pass null to the controller - this works
            if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.ContainsKey(bindingContext.FieldName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[bindingContext.FieldName]))
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            else
                
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new BreakSize()); // Todo set values for BreakSize from the form

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear to me what your problem is.  Do you *want* to pass a null? Are you complaining that a null is being passed? Are you asking whether "passing a null" for a model is a good practice?

Comment: Want to pass a NULL, not necessarliy looking for the best practice, need to find a solution that works.  Seems like using a model binder is overkill was hoping there is something I could maybe toss in the program.cs to override the default handling for this.

Comment: What happens when you call your method with a null for `size`?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Perhaps things have changed, but I believe that without any special binders at all, it's possible to simply pass a null to a controller.

Comment: What is the default handling you experience?

Comment: Seems like you can just initialize the view model to default values if you like.  Or set required attributes as needed... modelState can be checked or left unchecked.  As is, it seems like you're doing a lot of unnecessary checking that can be done automatically.

Comment: Thanks @AnnL. passing NULL without any custom binders instantiates a new object for the BreakSize parameter.

Comment: @pcalkins we are upgrading a .NET standard application, so there is several spots that we are checking for nulls the goal is to prevent a larger refactor with hopefully a setting that can be change to allow for NULLs.

Comment: You can use "?" to declare nullable types.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types  Don't know if it helps you but there is also a way to set whether empty strings convert automatically to nulls.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull?view=net-8.0

Comment: You might also check this migration topic...:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies#plan-your-migration  I think from 2.x to 3.x they changed so that non-nullable types were treated as [Required].  So modelState should take care of nulls bound to non-nullable types.

Comment: Did try the ?, there is an article that mentions complex types are instantiated using the public default constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#complex-types

Comment: I never saw an answer to @AnnL's question above. When you say "This solution does not work for all controller endpoints", what exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Does your endpoint fire? Do you get a specific response code? Do you get an exception in your endpoint? Without know specifically what the symptoms are, it's practically impossible to diagnose the disease.

Comment: Also, do you have a global exception handler (IExceptionHandler) logging data validation issues? If so, does it catch exceptions for the cases you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller action looks like this:

```
public void Endpoint(BreakSize size) { /**/ }
```

ASP.NET Core by default performs validation, i.e. it will check for nulls and throw 400. If you want to allow nulls, you need to use mark it as nullable:

```
public void Endpoint(BreakSize? size) { /**/ }
```

or

```
public void Endpoint([MaybeNull] BreakSize size) { /**/ }
```

Comment: Did try those methods.  No luck, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Optional Parameters: Your First Line of Defense

Make those complex type parameters optional using Nullable or T?. This allows null values to pass through without model binder surgery.
Example:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] BreakSize? breakSize)
{
    // Handle null or non-null breakSize like a boss
}
```

2. Query Parameters: A Sneaky Sidestep

Consider query parameters instead of body parameters for those optional data ninjas. They naturally embrace null values.
Example:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromQuery] BreakSize breakSize)
{
// Null or not, you got this
}
```

3. Custom Model Binding: For When You Need to Get Your Hands Dirty

Create a custom model binder to explicitly handle null values, giving you granular control over the binding process.
Example:

```
public class BreakSizeModelBinder : IModelBinder
  {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      // Implement logic to handle null values and bind properties from request
    }
  }
```

4. Action Filters: The Gatekeepers

Intercept requests and modify models before they reach action methods using action filters. Perfect for custom null-value handling and other preprocessing shenanigans.
Example:

```
public class NullBreakSizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
      // Check for null BreakSize parameter and handle it
    }
  }
```

5. Value Providers (ASP.NET Core 6+): The New Kids on the Block

Leverage value providers for declarative null-value handling, offering flexibility through dependency injection.
Example:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices] IValueProvider<BreakSize> valueProvider)
  {
    BreakSize breakSize = valueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext);
    // Handle null or non-null breakSize
  }
```

Frequency of null values: If null values are common, optional parameters or query parameters might be simpler.
Level of control needed: Custom model binding or action filters provide more granular control.
Dependency injection: Value providers can be injected as services for greater flexibility.
Readability and maintainability: Choose an approach that is clear and easy to understand for future developers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to pass a NULL complex type parameter in ASP.NET Core. You can use a nullable value type.

For example, if you have a complex type called `BreakSize` like so:

```
public class BreakSize?
{
    public int? h { get; set; }
    public int? w { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can use this type as a parameter in your controller endpoint. For example:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] BreakSize? breakSize)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

In case you call this endpoint with a null value for the
`{breakSize}` parameter, your controller action's `{breakSize}` variable will also be null.

The reason this method works is that the model binding system in ASP.NET Core supports nullable value types. The model binding system will automatically transform null values to `null` when a request is bound to a nullable value type.

Because it is more straightforward and doesn't require you to create any extra code, this technique is preferable than utilizing a custom model binder. Furthermore, it is compatible with all controller endpoints, independent of their level of complexity.